# Why ASP.NET Core WebApi wwwroot folder marked as ignored?

Tags: asp.net

I created a asp.net core project and the wwwroot folder is shown as ignored. How can I include it in the project?

Comment: What do you mean with ignored? What Editor are you using and how did you download `the project`?

Comment: I am using VisualStudio, the wwwroot folder shows with (-) sign and indicates, its being ignored. I didnt download any project, I created asp.net project. Let me know if there is any more information I can provide.

Comment: I found the reason for this. I didnt have node js installed and that was causing this issue.